# My minimum CPU clock looks like 2200mhz (ryzen 7 3800x) but when I type lscpu Ican see its below than 2200 mhz,how can I solve this?

Tags: boot, 20.04, cpu, amd-processor

> Frequency boost:                 enabled
>  CPU MHz:
> 2195.662
>  CPU max MHz:                     3900,0000
>  CPU min MHz:                     2200,0000
>  my pc specs are:
>  Msi
> Radeon 240(bought a 1050ti waiting to arrive)
>  Ryzen 3800x
> aorus x570 elite(also having boot issues)
>  2x 8gb 2400mhz
> rams
>  1x samsung 240gb 6gb/s ssd
>  xigmatek 650 w psu

and also I want to activate frequency boost without harming my CPU,thanks

Comment: 4 MHz below?  Isn't that close enough?

Comment: but it says minimum clock is 2200 mhz and its below 2200 mhz then something is clearly wrong with it

Comment: Consider it a rounding error.